# Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ then prove the following

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$.

(a) Prove that if $f'(x)\neq 1$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ has at most one fixed pont.

(b) Show that the function $$f(x) = x+\frac{1}{1+e^x}$$ has no fixed points.

(c) Prove that if $\sup\{\lvert f'(x)\rvert : x\in \mathbb{R}\} < 1$, then $f$ has a unique fixed point. (Hint: Start with an arbitrary real number $x_1$, and construct a sequence with $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$. Show that $\lvert s_{n+1}-s_n\rvert\leq c\lvert s_n-s_{n-1}\rvert$ where $c = \sup\{\lvert f'(x)\rvert : x\in \mathbb{R}\}$.)

**my attempt:**

for (a) we solve by contraction i.e, suppose there two fixed then by
{mean value theorem we got contradiction so only one fixed point 
for (c) since the sequence is convergent and f is continuous so f has fixed point i have only problem with (b)

Comment: What are you typing text **inside** a LaTeX environment?

Comment: There is no sequence in (b).

Comment: @edm....sorry i have problem (b) i edited now

Comment: It would be as simple as letting $f(x)=x$ and see what will happen.

Comment: @edm ..i try to solve with your idea

Comment: I would like to see some more argument for (c).

Comment: @edm... as your idea we got $e^x=\infty$ this means f has no fixed points?

Comment: your attempt seems to be one long run-on sentence

Comment: @suresh: No, $\infty$ is not included if we don't especially consider the question in broad fields of real numbers. Just like $1/x$ has no roots.

Comment: @XIAODAQU..thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

For b) fixed points means the solutions of $$f(x)=x \Leftrightarrow x+\frac{1}{1+e^x}=x \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{1+e^x} = 0$$ with no solution.